# plupload json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, plupload

I can't seem to make the response a json object.

the ajax function (url parameter to plupload) echoes the response like this:

```
echo json_encode(array(
  'foo'    => 3434,
  'error'  => 'omg error',
));

exit;
```

and in the FileUploaded event I'm evaluating that:

```
var json = eval('(' + response + ')');
console.log(json);
```

But I get a error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: can you post the json string?  Are you sure "response" contains it?

Comment: ok, the problem was the function parameter, which is actually a object and response is a property :| like `response.response`

Comment: Is "pluload" in the question title supposed to be "upload"?

Comment: no, it's the plupload script...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use jQuery `parseJSON` method.

```
var json = $.parseJSON(response);
```

Comment: I think internally it must be using `eval` itself but it is a best practice to use `$.parseJSON`

Comment: there is also JSON.parse which doesn't require jquery, although it requires either a modern browser or Crockford's JSON library

Comment: Rob, if you're using plupload you've already referenced jQuery so why would you not want to use it?!

Comment: current version of plupload does not depend on jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

As of v3.0 of jQuery, `$.parseJSON(response)` has been deprecated.

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/):

> As of jQuery 3.0, $.parseJSON is deprecated. To parse JSON strings use the native JSON.parse method instead.

The answer to above question is thus:

```
var json = JSON.parse(response);
```