# convert json string send with text/html headers to valid object

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have this php script

```
if (!$chunks || $chunk == $chunks - 1) {
// Strip the temp .part suffix off 
    rename("{$filePath}.part", $filePath);
    if( $content = $this->html_file_uploaded( $filePath ) ){

        die('{"Done" : "yee", "content" : "woe" , "id" : "id"}');
            }
```

and in JavaScript I want to do

```
 FileUploaded: function(up, file, info) {
    // Called when a file has finished uploading

    $('body').prepend('FileUploaded fired<br>'+info.Done);
```

but it returns undefined if I write it to the page

```
$('body').prepend('FileUploaded fired<br>'+info.Done);
```

`var info = $.parseJSON(info);` did not work for me.

how can I make it work?

**EDIT**
The JavaScript and php are from the [plupload api](http://www.plupload.com/example_events.php)

I don't want to use `json_encode`, unless I am told sending a string like this can never work, or is not reliable. I am interested how to convert the string to a valid object.
I use online [json string checker](http://www.freeformatter.com/json-formatter.html) and it says it is not valid, - Unable to format the JSON input. A `JSONObject` text must begin with '{' at character 1 near ''{'"Done" :'

Comment: What's the content of $content? Is it wrapped in double quotes?

Comment: some template content, but I get the same result if I just replace it with an ordinary string like "woe".

Comment: @Richard, Not sure how to help you with the JavaScript part, since you haven't posted **any** relevant JS code where you get your data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [plupload json response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298793/plupload-json-response)

Comment: In general, just `console.log(info)` to see how the info object is structured. Much faster than asking here...

Comment: i can't get info into the console, otherwise I would have seen it

Comment: thanks, for the duplicate link, but it was no help..I need to know why the json string is invalid..and possible duplicates are not the worst, it turns out I have a string that is invalid, so I am one step further..

Comment: the json is valid. put it into your checker without the single quotes around it. only:
`{"Done" : "yee", "content" : "woe" , "id" : "id"}`

Comment: thanks, I found that out also, but php puts it out as a string, I am still nowhere

Comment: yes json is always represented as a string. if `info` is exactly the string you put into your checker then `var info = $.parseJSON(info);` should work as expected

Comment: yes, I get what your saying, still why won't it work from what I receive? It returns TypeError: info is null in firebug

Comment: the `die` statement is inside an `if` block. are you sure your javascript function is called from php with exactlty this `die` statement? there might be other exit points.. more context would be very useful to debug this

Comment: yes that's why I gave the link to plupload, otherwise I would have to paste a lot. I found out that the info object is infact an object, but I am referencing it wrong, I can see this if I output info in firebug Object { response=

"{"Done" : "yee", "content" : "woe" , "id" : "id"}"

, status=

200

}

Comment: I have not changed it in anyway, literarely the same as the example and I receive the string in firebug exactly like I have shown you in my last comment, my question to you is--how to get this to a working object. response is the thing you get in return when your headers are text/html, right - together with status. How can I turn this string wich is doubleqouted into a json object?? puzzle,puzzle

Comment: `var obj = $.parseJSON(info.response);`

Comment: after that just reference `obj.Done`

Comment: @ lrsjng, thanks that is amazing, I have try'd all other possible variations, but this one is counterintuitive. Why does response get set as the prop of info? I have to think about that for a minute. Could you post your answer in an answer block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your callback function (referenced as `FileUploaded`) do

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(info.response);
```

now you can reference the response like `obj.Done`

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse()` is what you need. If this doesn't work, you're doing something wrong on php side.

NOTE: If you want to include JSON support in legacy browsers (who said IE7?), you need to include Douglas Crockford's JSON2.js from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Comment: thanks, the whole problem was that I was referencing the object wrong. So your suggestion was helpfull